# Can tex4ht use internal css instead of external css?

Tags: tex4ht

By default `tex4ht` uses external css, i.e., the generated HTML file contains a line like this:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jobname.css">
```

Can `jobname.css` but automatically inserted into the generated HTML file as internal css?

I.e., between `<style></style>` tags within the `<head>` section.

I want to create a standalone HTML file. I could post-process of course, but I'm hoping there's a built-in way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way, so you need to use the post-processing. It is quite easy using `make4ht` build files:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

-- this variable will hold contents of the CSS file
local csscontent

local function load_css(filename)
  local f = io.open(filename, "r")
  if f then
    local content = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    -- make sure that the inline CSS don't mess with make4ht DOM filters
    content = "<style type='text/css'>\n<!-- " .. content .. " -->\n</style>"
    return content
  end
end

-- this filter chain will insert CSS
local process = filter{
  function(html, par)
    local cssname = par.input .. ".css"
    -- TeX4ht can produce multiple HTML files. We will load the CSS file contents 
    -- only for the firts time, and cache it for the future use
    csscontent = csscontent or load_css(cssname)
    if csscontent then
      -- we use just string substitution to replace <link ...href="\jobname.css">
      -- the replacement function is used in order to prevent Lua errors caused by % characters in CSS
      html = html:gsub("<link[^>]+" .. cssname .. ".->", function(s) return csscontent  end)
    end
    return html
  end
}

Make:match("html$",  process)
```

I've use `make4ht-filter` library to post-process the HTML file. The `filter` function takes a table with post-processing functions. Each function works on output of the preceding function in the filter chain. In this case there is just one function, but more can be used.

The filter is executed on each output `HTML` file using `Make:match("html$",  process)`

You can pass the build file to `make4ht` using the `-e` option:

```
make4ht -e build.lua sample.tex
```

This example:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605478/2891
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello \textit{world}

{\huge\bfseries hello huge}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<style type='text/css'>
<!--   
/* start css.sty */
.cmti-10{ font-style: italic;}
.cmbx-12x-x-172{font-size:206%; font-weight: bold;}
p{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}
p.indent{text-indent:0;}
p + p{margin-top:1em;}
p + div, p + pre {margin-top:1em;}
div + p, pre + p {margin-top:1em;}
a { overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; hyphens: auto; }
@media print {div.crosslinks {visibility:hidden;}}
a img { border-top: 0; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; }
center { margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em; }
td center { margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em; }
.Canvas { position:relative; }
img.math{vertical-align:middle;}
div.par-math-display, div.math-display{text-align:center;}
li p.indent { text-indent: 0em }
li p:first-child{ margin-top:0em; }
li p:first-child{ margin-bottom; }
li p:last-child, li div:last-child { margin-bottom:0.5em; }
li p:first-child{ margin-bottom:0; }
li p~ul:last-child, li p~ol:last-child{ margin-bottom:0.5em; }
.enumerate1 {list-style-type:decimal;}
.enumerate2 {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
.enumerate3 {list-style-type:lower-roman;}
.enumerate4 {list-style-type:upper-alpha;}
div.newtheorem { margin-bottom: 2em; margin-top: 2em;}
.obeylines-h,.obeylines-v {white-space: nowrap; }
div.obeylines-v p { margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; }
.overline{ text-decoration:overline; }
.overline img{ border-top: 1px solid black; }
td.displaylines {text-align:center; white-space:nowrap;}
.centerline {text-align:center;}
.rightline {text-align:right;}
pre.verbatim {font-family: monospace,monospace; text-align:left; clear:both; }
.fbox {padding-left:3.0pt; padding-right:3.0pt; text-indent:0pt; border:solid black 0.4pt; }
div.fbox {display:table}
div.center div.fbox {text-align:center; clear:both; padding-left:3.0pt; padding-right:3.0pt; text-indent:0pt; border:solid black 0.4pt; }
div.minipage{width:100%;}
div.center, div.center div.center {text-align: center; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em;}
div.center div {text-align: left;}
div.flushright, div.flushright div.flushright {text-align: right;}
div.flushright div {text-align: left;}
div.flushleft {text-align: left;}
.underline{ text-decoration:underline; }
.underline img{ border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-bottom:1pt; }
.framebox-c, .framebox-l, .framebox-r { padding-left:3.0pt; padding-right:3.0pt; text-indent:0pt; border:solid black 0.4pt; }
.framebox-c {text-align:center;}
.framebox-l {text-align:left;}
.framebox-r {text-align:right;}
span.thank-mark{ vertical-align: super }
span.footnote-mark sup.textsuperscript, span.footnote-mark a sup.textsuperscript{ font-size:80%; }
div.tabular, div.center div.tabular {text-align: center; margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:0.5em; }
table.tabular td p{margin-top:0em;}
table.tabular {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
td p:first-child{ margin-top:0em; }
td p:last-child{ margin-bottom:0em; }
div.td00{ margin-left:0pt; margin-right:0pt; }
div.td01{ margin-left:0pt; margin-right:5pt; }
div.td10{ margin-left:5pt; margin-right:0pt; }
div.td11{ margin-left:5pt; margin-right:5pt; }
table[rules] {border-left:solid black 0.4pt; border-right:solid black 0.4pt; }
td.td00{ padding-left:0pt; padding-right:0pt; }
td.td01{ padding-left:0pt; padding-right:5pt; }
td.td10{ padding-left:5pt; padding-right:0pt; }
td.td11{ padding-left:5pt; padding-right:5pt; }
table[rules] {border-left:solid black 0.4pt; border-right:solid black 0.4pt; }
.hline hr, .cline hr{ height : 0px; margin:0px; }
.hline td, .cline td{ padding: 0; }
.hline hr, .cline hr{border:none;border-top:1px solid black;}
.tabbing-right {text-align:right;}
div.float, div.figure {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
div.float img {text-align:center;}
div.figure img {text-align:center;}
.marginpar,.reversemarginpar {width:20%; float:right; text-align:left; margin-left:auto; margin-top:0.5em; font-size:85%; text-decoration:underline;}
.marginpar p,.reversemarginpar p{margin-top:0.4em; margin-bottom:0.4em;}
.reversemarginpar{float:left;}
table.equation {width:100%;}
.equation td{text-align:center; }
td.equation { margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em; } 
td.equation-label { width:5%; text-align:center; }
td.eqnarray4 { width:5%; white-space: normal; }
td.eqnarray2 { width:5%; }
table.eqnarray-star, table.eqnarray {width:100%;}
div.eqnarray{text-align:center;}
div.array {text-align:center;}
div.pmatrix {text-align:center;}
table.pmatrix {width:100%;}
span.pmatrix img{vertical-align:middle;}
div.pmatrix {text-align:center;}
table.pmatrix {width:100%;}
span.bar-css {text-decoration:overline;}
table.tabular{border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
img.cdots{vertical-align:middle;}
.partToc a, .partToc, .likepartToc a, .likepartToc {line-height: 200%; font-weight:bold; font-size:110%;}
.index-item, .index-subitem, .index-subsubitem {display:block}
div.caption {text-indent:-2em; margin-left:3em; margin-right:1em; text-align:left;}
div.caption span.id{font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; }
h1.partHead{text-align: center}
p.bibitem { text-indent: -2em; margin-left: 2em; margin-top:0.6em; margin-bottom:0.6em; }
p.bibitem-p { text-indent: 0em; margin-left: 2em; margin-top:0.6em; margin-bottom:0.6em; }
.paragraphHead, .likeparagraphHead { margin-top:2em; font-weight: bold;}
.subparagraphHead, .likesubparagraphHead { font-weight: bold;}
.verse{white-space:nowrap; margin-left:2em}
div.maketitle {text-align:center;}
h2.titleHead{text-align:center;}
div.maketitle{ margin-bottom: 2em; }
div.author, div.date {text-align:center;}
div.thanks{text-align:left; margin-left:10%; font-size:85%; font-style:italic; }
div.author{white-space: nowrap;}
div.abstract p {margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%;}
div.abstract {width:100%;}
.abstracttitle{text-align:center;margin-bottom:1em;}
figure.float, div.figure {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
figure.float img, figure.figure img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
figure.figure {text-align:center;}
figcaption.caption {text-indent:-2em; margin-left:3em; margin-right:1em; text-align:center;}
figcaption.caption span.id{font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; }
p + figcaption, img + figcaption{margin-top: 1em;}
.abstract{margin:1em;}
/* end css.sty */

  -->
</style> 
<meta content='sample.tex' name='src' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>Hello <span class='cmti-10'>world</span>
</p><!-- l. 6 --><p class='indent'>   <span class='cmbx-12x-x-172'>hello huge</span>
</p>
    
</body> 
</html>
```